# Jquery Post, dies when I add javascript to returning content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I use JQuery to load data into a div

```
$.post("ajax/ajax_make.php", {
                type: $('#type').val()
            }, function(response){
                setTimeout("finishAjax('make', '"+escape(response)+"')", 100);
            });
```

It works, but when I add a line of script, it will not reload the visibility, though it still does load the content.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"><?PHP       
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `title` WHERE notlisted='1' && NOT bookid = 'title'
                 ") or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                if (!isset($green)){
                $green=array();
            }
            $books = $row['booktitles'];
            array_push($green, $books);
            }
            foreach ($green as $value){
                echo "$('#".$value." a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show')
    })";
            }
            ?> </script>
```

you can see it in action at http://www.biblenice.com/completebible/

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: The relevant content is the *actual* response sent and the *actual* usage of such. Neither of which is shown.

Comment: the question is, when I return the stuff, it doesn't reset the value of the fillme div to visible, it just keeps it display:none.  but If I take the javascript section out of the return, it works fine.

Comment: Where is the line that sets the div to visible?

Comment: finishAjax sets the content to fill, it is a call I looked it up, but couldn't figure out why adding javascript to the output would make the visibility not work.

Comment: Solved the problem, I just got rid of the fadout, which happened earlier in the code.  Thanks for the thought lucas

Comment: put a semi-colon at the end of `e.preventDefault()`